# update a list in swift UI with data from a local json file

Tags: json, swift, list, parsing, swiftui

I have a function that with a for cycle goes true a local json file called "data" take some data and pass this data to an array "storage" of type "DataModel" and at the end all has been save () with the function save()

until here looks like everything working, because if I print how many data inside my storage using storage.count the amount of data increased and more if I print the data read from the json file and pass to my storage array all data is there.

I want my list in swiftUI update once I press the button and display all data ready from the json

for debugging I try to create a function that load a data via 2 text box and save() .. and this working fine, I add my new value , save and the list automatic update.

this my DataModel

```
import Foundation

class DataModel:Identifiable , Codable {

    var nameApt : String
    var icaoCode : String

init(nameApt: String, icaoCode: String) {
    self.nameApt = nameApt
    self.icaoCode = icaoCode
}
}
```

this my DataManager

```
import UIKit
import Combine
class DataManager :ObservableObject {
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()

    var storage : [DataModel] = []
    typealias Storage = [DataModel]

    var filePath : String = ""

    init() { caricaDati() }
    func caricaDati() {
        // creiamo il percorso al file
        filePath = cartellaDocuments() + "\test.plist"

        // usiamo NSFileManager per sapere se esiste un file a quel percorso
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {

            // se c'è de-archiviamo il file di testo nell'array
            // serve il blocco do try catch
            do {
                // proviamo a caricare il file dal percorso creato in precedenza
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                // creiamo il decoder
                let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
                // proviamo a decodificare il file nell'array
                storage = try decoder.decode(Storage.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                // se non ce la fa scriviamo in console l'errore
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        } else {
            let tem = DataModel(nameApt: "NewDasmi", icaoCode: "DAMI")
            storage = [tem]
            salva()
        }
    }

    func salva() {
        objectWillChange.send()
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormat = .xml // impostiamo l'output corretto
        // serve il blocco do try catch
        do {
            // proviamo a codificare l'array
            let data = try encoder.encode(storage)
            // proviamo a salvare l'array codificato nel file
            try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        } catch {
            // se non ce la fa scriviamo in console l'errore
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    // for debugging this function in order to see if my list update with manual insertion

    func creaData (nomeApt: String, icao: String) {
        let temporVar = DataModel(nameApt: nomeApt, icaoCode: icao)
        self.storage.append(temporVar)
        salva()
    }

    func open (fileName : String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let datafile = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl,options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let json = JSON(data:datafile)


                let caricaDati = DataModel(nameApt: "TEST", icaoCode: "TEST")
                var i =  0
                for _ in 0...json.count {
                    caricaDati.nameApt = json[i]["airportName"].stringValue
                    caricaDati.icaoCode = json[i]["airportCode"].stringValue
                    i=i+1
                    objectWillChange.send() 
                    self.storage.append(caricaDati)
                    print(caricaDati.nameApt)
                    print(caricaDati.icaoCode)
                }
                salva()
                print(storage.count) //  count of item in array storage


            }catch {
                print("erroree")
            }

        }
    }
    func cartellaDocuments() -> String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        //print(paths[0])
        return paths[0]
    }
}
```

and here my interface in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ ObservedObject var dm : DataManager

    @State var nomeApt : String = ""
    @State var icaoApt : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("nome", text: $nomeApt)
                TextField("icao", text: $icaoApt)
                Button(action: {

                    // for debugging just to see if the list update automatically with new item manually inserted! and it works...
                    self.dm.creaData(nomeApt: self.nomeApt, icao: self.icaoApt)
                    // not updating with json file
                    self.dm.open(fileName: "data")
                }) {
                    Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Button"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
            }
            List{
                ForEach (dm.storage) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.nameApt)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(item.icaoCode)
                    }

            }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(dm: DataManager())
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved by using the function crea data inside the function open.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using the function crea data inside the function open

```
   func creaData (nomeApt: String, icao: String) {
        let temporVar = DataModel(nameApt: nomeApt, icaoCode: icao)
        self.storage.append(temporVar)
        salva()
    }

    func open (fileName : String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let datafile = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl,options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let json = JSON(data:datafile)
                var i = 0
                for _ in 0...json.count {
                    let caricaDati = DataModel(nameApt: "TEST", icaoCode: "TEST")
                    caricaDati.nameApt = json[i]["airportName"].stringValue
                    caricaDati.icaoCode = json[i]["airportCode"].stringValue
                    creaData(nomeApt: caricaDati.nameApt, icao: caricaDati.icaoCode)
                    i = i+1
                }
                salva()
                print(storage.count)



            }catch {
                print("erroree")
            }

        }
    }
```